# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/mapsforge/core/model/BoundingBox - OSMOSIS

Tags: flutter, bounding-box, osmosis

When trying to convert the OpenStreetMap file (.osm) to a Linker Address Map (.map) file I got this error. what's the solution would be?
here is the log:

```
C:\Users\ajual\Desktop\osmosis-0.40.1\bin>osmosis --rx file=mapone.osm --mw kerala.map type=hd bbox=9.4692,77.1366,9.3737,76.9621
Sep 20, 2023 10:15:12 AM org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.Osmosis run
INFO: Osmosis Version 0.40.1
Sep 20, 2023 10:15:13 AM org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.Osmosis run
INFO: Preparing pipeline.
Sep 20, 2023 10:15:13 AM org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.Osmosis main
SEVERE: Execution aborted.
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/mapsforge/core/model/BoundingBox
        at org.mapsforge.map.writer.model.MapWriterConfiguration.addBboxConfiguration(MapWriterConfiguration.java:66)
        at org.mapsforge.map.writer.osmosis.MapFileWriterFactory.createTaskManagerImpl(MapFileWriterFactory.java:55)
        at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.pipeline.common.TaskManagerFactory.createTaskManager(TaskManagerFactory.java:60)
        at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.pipeline.common.Pipeline.buildTasks(Pipeline.java:50)
        at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.pipeline.common.Pipeline.prepare(Pipeline.java:112)
        at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.Osmosis.run(Osmosis.java:86)
        at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.Osmosis.main(Osmosis.java:37)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchStandard(Launcher.java:329)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:239)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:47)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.mapsforge.core.model.BoundingBox
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:244)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:230)
        ... 16 more
```